# Synthesis Problem?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: Synthesis question]

What I tried to do is this: Opening the epoxide using $\ce{^-OCH2CH2CH3}$.
But then I have two alcohols and I get stuck. It's possible in one way but takes more than 4 steps...

Comment: One of the most helpful things to do in these types of problems is mapping the carbon skeleton of the starting material onto the product. So, I see the the propyl ether is formed from simple alkylation, and the rest of the carbon skeleton is already in place. The only issue is I need to break the terminal C-O bond of the epoxide, which we can do with a nucleophilic hydride source. That will give an alcohol that you can oxidize. I'll leave you to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - rearrange the terminal epoxide to the methyl ketone using Pd(OAc)2, PBu3 in refluxing toluene as desribed in this JOC paper [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00103a005).  It is not necessary to protect the alcohol as the paper describes the transformation of a very similar hdyroxy epoxide.

Step 2 - deprotonate the alcohol using NaH/THF at low temperature and quench with n-propyl iodide to give the required product.

Comment: Thank you so much btw :) Any simpler ways since this is an O-chem 1/2 problem.

Comment: @Waylander: May have a problem with enolate formation although pKa's are in your favor. Depends on the relative rates of alkylation.

Comment: @user55119 alternatively you could mesylate the alcohol (MsCl/Et3N) then react with the anion of 1-propanol.

Comment: @SharbelDamouni  alternatively you could react the epoxide with DABCO to do a Meinwald rearrangement to the methyl ketone - see https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.joc.8b03171

Comment: @Waylander: The mesylate also has the problem of enolate formation leading to cyclopropylmethyl ketone or cyclopentanone whan the the mesylate is exposed to CH3CH2CH2O-.

Comment: @user55119 With a pKa difference of approx 3.5 units between the -OH and ketone alpha protons,  I think the first method of adding 1eq NaH portionwise to a mixture of the keto-alcohol and n-propyl iodide will give a decent yield

Comment: Perhaps so. I found a Russian paper that opens cyclopropyl methyl ketone with C1-C3 alcohols in the presence of Cu(II) and Pd(II) salts. I think all of these methods involve reactions too sophisticated for intro organic chemistry. I suspect a ketalization was expected at some point.